# Selenium Webdriver (Java) connect/interoperate with a Firefox extension/plugin

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-webdriver

i am looking for a way to connect out of the Selenium Webdriver to a Firefox extension/plugin.
I want to start a function from the firefox extension out of the api of the selenium Webdriver. Could this be possible?
I know that i can call javascript code which is inside a page, but not inside a firefox extension.

If it is not possible with selenium webdriver, is there another way to connect, maybe with java?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One of way, how you could do this, is:

- [Create firefox profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) and name it somehow you know what it is. e.g. `SELENIUM`
- Install addon to this profile. In general, make that profile suitable for the tests.
- When initializing the Webdriver:

  ```
   ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
   FirefoxProfile desiredProfile = allProfiles.getProfile("SELENIUM");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredProfile);
  ```

Comment: Actually that would add a Plugin to my Webdriver, that is not my problem. How can i say something like "Know press this Button" from the plugin i have added to my webdriver (or actually call the javascript function behind the button) ?